# IntelliJ - How to add a default run configuration to a user created project template?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I have my own user created project template that spawns a Main.java file under a src package. I would like the project template to also have a particular run configuration that executes the Main.java file with the VM parameter

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/lwjgl-2.9.1/native/linux
```

I'm having a lot of trouble finding this in the documentation. Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

I'm running IntelliJ 13.1. The following is a screenshot of the run configuration I would like to be part of the project template, which was created from the project on the left.

[image]

Comment: What idea version and what kind of a template? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I updated my post to reflect that information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your screenshot, you have two categories: Application and Defaults. If you expand Defaults, it will list Application. Click on the Application and set the default value there. Any runtime configuration built from the default will carry those default values from now on.